# magento: how to change frontend labels?

Tags: magento, edit, frontend, label

I'm new magento user. I'm building my website and cant edit frontend labels to my language. I mean, i.e. change "search" label to "procurar", can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Magento comes with translation directories in;

```
app/locale/[country_code]
```

Go and download the language pack for your country, here:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/customer-experience/internationalization-localization.html

Add the files to the

```
app/locale/[your country code] directory.
```

By default you will be using the en_US version.  To change this, go to admin and navigate to;

system > configuration (from the top menu)

Then in the left menu, go to 'General' and find 'Locale Options', under there choose your 'Locale' country and save.  Clear your cache, and voila, you are translated.

Best
Tom

Comment: Yeah... Uhm... Make sure you copy the language files before listening to this answer though...

Comment: *slaps face* you're absolutely right, sorry i missed that. answer edited

Comment: Thank you guys for the tips. It is not translated yet but I'm considering the fact of having just one store (the default one), maybe I should create others.